# SQL SELECT JOIN Query over multiple tables

Tags: sql, erp

I’m trying to get data about Installations in buildings. The problem is that one building can have multiple installations and I’m unsure how to adjust my sql for that as the initial table I query only holds the relations that own the buildings.
Here’s the situation.
Table 1 (RELRLGRP) holds the id of the group the relations that own the buildings that have the installations that have the data I need.

This is what I have so far, I’m worried I shouldn’t use this many joins in an SQL statement  but cannot find a quicker link between the information I need from my starting point at the group of relations till the installation data I seek in the BORGINST table. Please disregard the select portion of the statement (removed it for clarity).

```
SELECT *
FROM RELRLGRP A
JOIN RELATION R ON A.RELATION_GC_ID = R.GC_ID 
JOIN BUILDING G ON R.CODE = G.GC_CODE
JOIN INSTALL I ON G.GC_CODE = I.GC_CODE
JOIN BORGINST B ON I.GC_ID = B.GC_ID
WHERE A.RELGROUP_GC_ID LIKE '100109' (<- the group the relations belong to)
```

I’ve done some rudimentary SQL but this linking through tables is new territory for me, in that sense I’d be happy to know if this many join statements are the way to go or if I should head a different route entirely.

Comment: This only 5 tables. This is nothing. What is the concern?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff , I'll try to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JesseJ - Since I don't know all the columns that exist in your tables, I am going to assume that you are joining on primary keys. If this is the case, your solution may be the only one available to link the RELRLGRP to the BORGINST table.

Linking multiple tables like you are doing can be common in a normalized database.

**Example:**

[image: Finding the State in which a Sales Transaction Happened]

In the example I posted, in order to find the State where a particular transaction happened, you have to link all the tables together. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for your awser @Master_Mahan the primary keys comment combined with the reassurance that I was on the right path was  a .. *key insight*. Got the right query in a few short minutes after reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sweat it: I have views with three times as many joins. Every join does add complexity and suck more processor, but it really comes down to performance: if this process doesn't finish as quickly as you need it to, you can look into other methods, but otherwise multiple joins like this are perfectly fine.